# node.js readdir with encoding

Tags: node.js, encoding

How I can readdir that contains filename with non utf-8 characters(e.g. cp1251)?

```
fs.readdir("./dir1", function(err, files){
    console.log(files[0], new Buffer(files[0]));

});
```

response:
'Forget (������).mp3', Buffer <46 6f 72 67 65 74 20 28 ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd 29 2e 6d 70 33>

upd: files was uploaded from proftpd in cp1251 encoding name

```
# ls dir1
Forget (������).mp3
```

upd2:

```
ls dir1 | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8
Forget (гитара).mp3
```

Comment: What's the name of the file?

Comment: What OS? Cannot reproduce on Linux. (Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: Tested it on OS X 10.8.4, and it works perfectly - for the file name you gave as well as for some sample Chinese characters.

Comment: Ubuntu. May be I have problems with locale?

Comment: What happens when you use `console.log(files[0], (new Buffer(files[0])).toString('utf8'))`?

Comment: And, what does `console.log('гитара');` print to your terminal?

Comment: console.log('гитара'); // гитара - ok

Comment: console.log(files[0], (new Buffer(files[0])).toString('utf8')) // Forget (������).mp3 - not ok

Comment: I think the filenames are encoded in cp1251 and node cannot understand the filenames it reads (it uses utf-8 by default). See this package which can help you in encoding conversion https://npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the upload via FTP already got the characters wrong ... try renaming the file manually, and re-run your Node.js app again. This time, it should work :-)

You can see that the file name is broken already in the buffer:

```
46 6f 72 67 65 74 20 28 ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd
ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd 29 2e 6d 70 33
```

The term `ef bf bd` is repeated six times, which perfectly matches the six-times occurence of the invalid character, and very obviously it's not the original string `гитара`.